# What is the Adaptive Payments URL for HTTP redirect?

Tags: paypal

I have working code that returns a paykey for paypal's adaptive payments API, however I can't seem to find what url to redirect to in the REST documentation.

This is the one I found in a tutorial:

```
$url = 'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=' . $verb['payKey'];
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Which gives the error message:
"This transaction has already been approved. Please visit your PayPal Account Overview to see the details."

I got the Paykey to work in an iframe, but that was being buggy so I decided to use a redirect for now, but I can't seem to find the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sandbox API it is:
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-...`

For the Live API it is:
`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-...`

with the end of the paykey where the `...`s are.